# Dissociated press algorithm using ngram

Tags: algorithm

I solve that kind of algorithm, and stuck how does algorithm works.

Dissociated press algorithm is https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dissociated_press

N gram - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/N-gram

can make possible random string in consecutive string, so It can be implemented.

> The dissociated press algorithm starts by printing a random n-gram.
> Then it takes the last n-1 words it has printed, and chooses a random
> n-gram that starts with these n-1 words. It prints the last word of
> this n-gram, and repeats. So every consecutive n words of the output
> text are an n-gram of the original text. In can sometimes happen that
> the original text contains no n-gram starting with the n-1 words just
> printed. In this case, the algorithm simply stops.

actually I don't know. how It is terminated.

```
ngram(1,2) ngram(2,3) ngram (3,4) ........ T T
```

is any example for me? I can't understand its text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, first you split the test into n-grams:

> The dissociated press algorithm starts by printing a random n-gram.

becomes (for n = 4)

- the dissociated press algorithm
- dissociated press algorithm starts
- press algorithm starts by
- algorithm starts by printing
- starts by printing a
- by printing a random
- printing a random n-gram

etc. Then, you start with any n-gram you like, and start adding words that would complete last `n-1` words of the text built so far to a known n-gram. As a result, the text you create seems almost readable — the larger `n` is, the more readable text you'll have.

Answer (score 0):

It is not an awfully complex algorithm. The given version runs quite well:

```
public class Dissociator {

// Required size of the overlap
int overlapSize = 8;

// Size of the fragment
int fragmentSize = overlapSize;

// The initial sequence to dissociate, characters or words (could also dissociate some other objects).
ArrayList<String> initial;

boolean space;
boolean wordMode;

Random r = new Random(System.currentTimeMillis());

// Dissociate the given string. 
public String dissociate(String in) {

    ArrayList<String> a;
    if (wordMode)
        a = wordBased(in);
    else
        a = charBased(in);

    ArrayList<String> out = dissociate(a);

    StringBuilder b = new StringBuilder(out.size());
    for (String s : out) {
        b.append(s);
        if (wordMode)
            b.append(' ');
    }

    return b.toString();
}

/**
 * Run dissociation algorithm
 * 
 * @param input the initial sequence
 * @return the dissociated sequence.
 */
public ArrayList<String> dissociate(ArrayList<String> input) {

    initial = input;
    ArrayList<String> out = new ArrayList<String>();

    while (out.size() < input.size()) {
        int size = r.nextInt(overlapSize);
        if (size == 0)
            size = 1;

        ArrayList<String> tail = getTailOf(out, size);

        // Find random sequence in the input that matches the tail
        int p = r.nextInt(input.size() - 1) + 1; // Avoid zero.
        int was = p - 1; // This variable allows to break dissociation if it is not possible to find 
        // the acceptable continuation.

        boolean ok = false;

        if (tail.size() > 0)
            do {
                while (input.get(p).equals(tail.get(0)) && p != was)
                    p = (p + 1) % input.size();

                for (int j = 1; j < tail.size(); j++)
                    if (j + p < input.size()) {
                        if (!tail.get(j).equals(input.get(j + p))) {
                            ok = false;
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                ok = true;
            } while (!ok && p != was);

        for (int j = p; j < Math.min(p + fragmentSize, input.size()); j++)
            out.add(input.get(j));
    }
    return out;
}

//  Get the tail of the given size.
private ArrayList<String> getTailOf(ArrayList<String> out, int size) {
    if (size >= out.size())
        return out;
    else {
        ArrayList<String> r = new ArrayList<String>(size);
        for (int p = out.size() - size; p < out.size(); p++) {
            r.add(out.get(p));
        }
        return r;
    }
}

private static ArrayList<String> charBased(String in) {
    ArrayList<String> is = new ArrayList<String>();
    for (int i = 0; i < in.length(); i++)
        is.add(in.substring(i, i + 1));
    return is;
}

private static ArrayList<String> wordBased(String in) {
    ArrayList<String> is = new ArrayList<String>();
    StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(in, " ,:()?!\"'");
    while (st.hasMoreTokens())
        is.add(st.nextToken());
    return is;
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    String in;
    File f = new File(args[0]);
    BufferedReader r = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(f));
    String sr;
    StringBuilder bb = new StringBuilder((int) f.length());
    while ((sr = r.readLine()) != null) {
        bb.append(sr);
        bb.append(' ');
    }

    in = bb.toString();
    Dissociator d = new Dissociator();

    String b = d.dissociate(in);
    System.out.println(b);

}
}
```